# Why are my class functions being "undefined" in main am i missing something in the code?

Tags: c++

Functions in the class itself work just fine, the error seems a bit odd I don't get where the issue is.
Class Header//too long

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
    int isIdentical;
    int sum;
    int sum1;
    int sum2;
public:
    bool checkBSTidentical(Node* x, Node* y);
    int BSTidentical(Node* firstTree, Node* secondTree);
    int BSTnotIdentical(Node* firstTree, Node* secondTree);
    int BSTsum(Node* x);
    int compareBST(Node* root1, Node* root2);
    Node* build(int data);
    Node* insert(Node* node, int Value);
    void in(Node* root);
};
```

Class CPP // too long

Main //All class functions are not defined although I declared the class

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Node* tree1 = NULL;
    Node* tree2 = NULL;
    int x;
    tree1 = insert(tree1, 50); 
    tree1 = insert(tree1, 40);
    tree1 = insert(tree1, 30);
    tree1 = insert(tree1, 20);
    tree1 = insert(tree1, 10);
    cout << "Binary Tree 1: " << endl;
    in(tree1);
    cout << endl;
    tree2 = insert(tree2, 50);
    tree2 = insert(tree2, 40);
    tree2 = insert(tree2, 30);
    tree2 = insert(tree2, 20);
    tree2 = insert(tree2, 10);
    cout << "Binary Tree 2: " << endl;
    in(tree2);
    cout << endl;
    x = compareBST(tree1, tree2);
    cout << "Result: " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the class itself but it kept saying I cant as most of the text is code

Comment: what is the compiler error you are getting?

Comment: insert identifier not found and same for all the other functions

Comment: I guess you compile only main.cpp, but not BinarySearchTree.cpp. You need to compile both source files to one program (or compile both source files to object files, and then link all object files to one program).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`insert()`, `in()`, `compareBST()`, those are all non-static methods of the `BinarySearchTree` class, but your `main()` is trying to call them as if they were standalone functions instead. That is why you are getting "identifier not found" errors. You need to call them on an object instance of `BinarySearchTree`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree bsTree;
    Node* tree1 = NULL;
    Node* tree2 = NULL;
    int x;
    tree1 = bsTree.insert(tree1, 50); 
    tree1 = bsTree.insert(tree1, 40);
    tree1 = bsTree.insert(tree1, 30);
    tree1 = bsTree.insert(tree1, 20);
    tree1 = bsTree.insert(tree1, 10);
    cout << "Binary Tree 1: " << endl;
    bsTree.in(tree1);
    cout << endl;
    tree2 = bsTree.insert(tree2, 50);
    tree2 = bsTree.insert(tree2, 40);
    tree2 = bsTree.insert(tree2, 30);
    tree2 = bsTree.insert(tree2, 20);
    tree2 = bsTree.insert(tree2, 10);
    cout << "Binary Tree 2: " << endl;
    bsTree.in(tree2);
    cout << endl;
    x = bsTree.compareBST(tree1, tree2);
    cout << "Result: " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```